# Unclosed IO resources disrupt input at next shell prompt

Tags: terminal, io

Sometimes when I run a terminal program that spawns a child process, (e.g. `IO.popen` in a Ruby script), if the IO handle for the subprocess is not properly cleaned up (e.g. `IO.close`), then when the program exits and a new shell prompt is presented, I find that my terminal's input doesn't work correctly.

For example, arrow keys and meta or ctrl modified keystrokes, rather than triggering my configured key bindings, instead output escape sequences (e.g. `^[<key>`) to the terminal prompt. For instance, if I hit `<M-o>` three times, it looks like:

```
$ ^[o^[o^[o
```

When in this state, pressing `<C-c>` creates a new prompt that no longer has this issue. So it appears that my terminal is being left in a strange state due to the unclosed IO resources when the previous process terminated. Can someone explain what exactly is happening?

Comment: You're going to have to explain to people what shell (and hence what command-line editing library) you are using and why you think that ESC followed by "o" is not the correct escape sequence for your terminal emulator to be generating when you press the key chord Alt+O.

Comment: @JdeBP The shell is `zsh` so the command line editor is `zle`. In my `zshrc`, there is a configured binding for `\eo` which typically works, except in the situation I describe, in which the text representation of the sequence (`^[o`) is printed to the prompt. In fact, any key chord that is not an unmodified alphanumeric key acts this way-- arrow keys and ctrl-modified keys also print escape sequences to the prompt.

Comment: This is not an explanation of why you think that sending ESC followed by "o" is the terminal "in a strange state".  On the contrary, it is an explanation that there is nothing at all wrong with the terminal state and that your terminal is sending exactly the desired escape sequence all along.  It is impossible for answerers to give an explanation for a "strange" terminal state, where the terminal "doesn't work correctly", that isn't in fact the case in the first place.

Comment: @JdeBP My question clearly explains the problem I am facing-- escape sequences are printed to the prompt rather than triggering the configured key bindings as typically occurs. *Something* is in an unusual state and is causing this difficulty. I am hazy as to *what* is in the strange state (terminal, shell, something else?), which is why I am posting a question on a Q/A board. If you have some insight to share or can correct my terminology, then please do.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like xterm, along with bash.  The [default bash configuration](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#bash_meta_mode) sets meta-mode, and some program turns it off (both via an escape sequence), and bash's built-in reset restores that.

You can probably make it work the way you want by sending the result of

```
tput smm
```

in your prompt-string (with the usual caveat that it has to be bracketed by `\[` and `\]` to tell bash to ignore the "width" of that string).

Comment: Thanks for this answer-- I've since discovered that the cause of the problem is not ANSI escape sequences, but unclosed I/O resources, if you have any insight and want to update.